# Define a sequence $\{y_n\}$ by $y_{2n-1}=x_n$ and $y_{2n}=x$. Which of the following are true?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let  $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $x_n$ be a sequence in $X$. Let $x\in X$. Define a sequence $\{y_n\}$ by $$y_{2n-1}=x_n,y_{2n}=x,n\in \mathbb N$$ Which of the following statements are correct?

(A) If $x_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$, Then the sequence  $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy.

(B) If the sequence  $\{y_n\}$ is cauchy, then  $x_n\to x$ as $n\to \infty$.

(C) Let $f:X\to X$ be a mapping that maps Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences. Then $f$ is continuous.

My attempt

(A) If $x_n\to x$. Hence, $y_n \to x$. Every convergent sequence is cauchy.

(B) Since Given space is not complete, We know that $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy $\implies$  $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. But need not converges. I am not able to cook counter examples.

(C) We want to prove $f: X\to X$ is continuous. $x,y\in X$. Let us try to prove by contradiction.  Suppose $f$ is not continuous. So, there is $x\in X$,there is an $\epsilon_o \in \mathbb R^+$ and $\forall \delta \in \mathbb R^+$: $d(x,y)\leq\delta \implies d(f(y),f(x))\ge \epsilon_o$. For the same $\epsilon_o$, any $\delta \in \mathbb R^+$ there is $N(\delta):\forall n,m\geq N(\delta) \implies d(x_n,x_m)<\delta$ and $d(f(x_n),f(x_m))\ge \epsilon_o$. So, $f(x_n)$ is not a cauchy sequence. Which contradicts our assumption. Hence, (C) is true. Am I correct?

Comment: For (B) you are given a candidate limit $x$, so lack of completeness is not an issue here.

Comment: Thank you. Cauchy sequnce with convergent subsequence converges. Thank you for remembering the result :)

Comment: The point of (A),(B) is to use them to show (C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) Correct. Your argument is fine.

(B) Correct. Cauchy sequences with a convergent subsequence are convergent, even if the space is not complete.

(C) Correct. Let $x=\lim x_n$, $y_{2n-1}=x_n$ and $y_{2n}=x$. By (A), ${y_n}$ is Cauchy. Then ${f(y_n)}$ is Cauchy by hypothesis. Since ${f(y_{2n})}={f(x)}$, it follows by (B) that $f(y_n)$ converges and $\lim f(y_n)=f(x)$. Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: I think Question (C) is a little more general.

Comment: What about my arguments for (C)?

Comment: @copper.hat Indeed. See [Cauchy-continuous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-continuous_function) for an example.

Comment: @Unknownx I think it is alright too. Although it could be a bit more clear.

Comment: This actually implies [uniform continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2275265/function-maps-cauchy-sequences-to-cauchy-sequences-prove-uniform-continuity)

Comment: @YuiToCheng It doesn't. It's uniform continuity that implies Cauchy continuity not the other way around. There is a counter example for this in the link above. Maybe the key is that $(X, d)$ should be complete.

Comment: If the domain is totally bounded one can conclude uniform continuity.

Answer (score 0):

For (C), suppose $x_n \to x$. Then $x_n$ is Cauchy and hence so is $f(x_n)$.

We want to show that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Note that the sequence $x_1,x,x_2,x,x_3,x,...$ is Cauchy from (A). Hence $f(x_1),f(x),...$ is
also Cauchy and from (B) we see that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$, hence $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Very nice proof. Thank you verymuch :)

Comment: Often when you get problems with parts there is a connection, so it is worth considering in your approach.